# angularjs $resource non-callback pattern not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource, angularjs-factory

I found that the document from angularjs website says I could do something in my factory like this:

```
 var speicialProducts = [];

 factory.getFeatureProducts = function () {
    if ($.isEmptyObject(specialProducts)) {
        specialProducts = $resource('index.php/products/featureProducts').query().$promise.then(function(data){
            return data;
            // return data.content;
        });
    }
    return specialProducts;
}
```

and then in my controller I do:

```
$scope.specialProducts = specialProductFactory.getFeatureProducts();
```

But somehow the angularjs doesn't fill up the scope model when the data is been correctly returned.

I did try to do:

```
var speicialProducts = [];

 factory.getFeatureProducts = function () {
    if ($.isEmptyObject(specialProducts)) {
        specialProducts = $resource('index.php/products/featureProducts').query();
    }
    return specialProducts;
}
```

This is working, but I want to do something to assign part of the returned data to specialProducts but not the entire returned data (like what I did in the comment part in the first code example ***return data.content***). So any ideas I could make this works?

if there are some jsfiddle examples that will be great. 
Thanks

Comment: The last thing I want to change is the **$scope.specialProducts = specialProductFactory.getFeatureProducts();**, because I might want this pattern for the rest of possible datasource need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 if ($.isEmptyObject(specialProducts)) {
        $resource('index.php/products/featureProducts').query().$promise.then(function(data){
            angular.foreach(data,function(item) {
                 specialProducts.push(item);
            });
        });
    }
```

But in your controller you need to know when the data was returned from remote call for which you can watch over the `specialProducts` array.

**Update**: Better would be to use promises, but in this case

`$scope.specialProducts = specialProductFactory.getFeatureProducts();`

would fill the array in future. To know when you need to watch

`$scope.$watchCollection("specialProducts",function(data) { //Called when data updated});`

I strongly suggest you work with promise based API and use the `then` methods to get handle async responses.

Comment: how should I use it in controller? also **$scope.specialProducts = specialProductFactory.getFeatureProducts();** ?

Comment: Thank you, the $promise way is working, I just want to confirm if I can do it in a assignment way so that the code will look more simple and angular should fill up the $promise when the data return for me. But After I search a lot in the web, seems the promise and then are more common way of doing, so thank you